# Reproducción de audio usando el propio reproductor de Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

Megustaria saber como hago para crea una aplicación que al precionar un boton, automaticamente se active el productor de audio de android.
aqui un ejemplo:
Esto lo agregue al manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

```
boton1.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            val data = Uri.parse("Download:///" + "/audionline.mp3")
            intent.setDataAndType(data, "audio/mp3")
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Recuerda agregar lo que realizaste o investigaste, revisa [ask]. Te refieres a MediaPlayer?

Comment: Lo he agregado arriba.

Answer (score 0):

Me puse a leer como es la forma en kotlin, debido a que me dedico a android en java.
asi que decidi sacar parte del codigo de aca [Ejemplo de media player](https://www.javatpoint.com/kotlin-android-media-player).

```
 playBtn.setOnClickListener{  
            if(pause){  
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.currentPosition)  
                mediaPlayer.start()  
                pause = false  
                Toast.makeText(this,"media playing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()  
            }else{  
  
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext,R.raw.school_bell)  
                mediaPlayer.start()  
                Toast.makeText(this,"media playing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()  
  
            }
```

Este codigo lo que hace es reproducir la cancion en dos situaciones cuando esta pausada o cuando toco play por primera vez.